# Autohotkey unable to kill a process

Tags: winapi, process, autohotkey

I have facing some issues with svchost going out of control at times and making my system unstable. Mostly i just kill it manually, but i decided to write an AHK script to do that automatically everytime if starts using too much memory.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance force


;--------------------------------------------------------------
;    Variables
;--------------------------------------------------------------
minMemMB = 200
minCPUPercentage = 50

Loop
{
    for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select IDProcess, PercentProcessorTime, WorkingSet from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where Name like '%svchost%'")

    PID = % process.IDProcess
    CPU = % process.PercentProcessorTime
    MEM = % Round(process.WorkingSet/1000000)
    FormatTime, TIME

    if (CPU > minCPUPercentage or MEM > minMemMB)
        {
            Process, Close, %PID%
            sleep, 2000
            if ErrorLevel = %PID%  
                FileAppend,
                (
                    Killed, %PID% , %CPU% , %MEM%, %TIME% `r`n
                ), log.csv
            else
                FileAppend,
                (
                    Failed, %PID% , %CPU% , %MEM%, %TIME% `r`n
                ), log.csv
        }

}
```

My code works fine in identifying when svchost has exceeded the accepted amount of memory it should take. But it fails in killing it. my log is full of entries like this:

```
Failed  624 0   1036     11:15 PM Wednesday  May 13 2015
Failed  7408    68  65   12:36 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
Failed  7408    92  121  12:37 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
Failed  7408    80  142  12:39 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
Failed  7408    55  176  12:39 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
Failed  7408    99  149  12:46 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
Failed  7408    80  150  12:53 AM Thursday   May 14 2015
```

Can someone help me in this?
Should I use run + taskkill instead?
Or is there a WMI command I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Killing svchost.exe (service host process) is probably a bad idea. An instance of svchost usually takes care of multiple services and if you kill it all the services that run under it will stop.
You should rather try to find out which service is causing the system to become unstable, then find out which program this service is part of and then update or uninstall that program... or in the worst case stop the service.
You could also disable the service to keep it from starting automatically when windows does.

I recommend the [process explorer from sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Just hover over an svchost process and a tooltip will show you which services it currently hosts.

To disable or stop a service go here: `Win+R -> services.msc -> Enter`

Comment: Forivin, I am aware that svchost is a container process. However, i use a corporate laptop and this issue is specific to some IT policies. It only comes up when I have Dota running along with Firefox and Flashplayer.

Anyway, there's no issue in killing the process itself. I just want to automate the process so that i dont have to alt+tab out of a game myself every time to do that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `this issue is specific to some IT policies`? Especially on a corporate laptop, I would never ever just kill an svchost process. Only because it looks like nothing bad happened, doesn't mean that's true. In theory you could cause a process, that relies on specific services, to corrupt data on your drives and cause backup and security mechanisms to fail... Just check what services the svchost process is hosting, track down which service is responsible and fix the issue permanently instead of killing svchosts on a regular basis.